# Print a list of objects with lists inside lists

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to print this list with sub-items, all separated by numbers, like:

```
1 item 1
2 item 2
2.1 Item 2 sub 1
2.2 item 2 sub 2
2.2.1 item 2 sub 2 sub 1
3 last
```

That is:

1. Item numbers are 1-based.
2. Items should be printed with a "row header" preceding it displaying its item number.
3. When an item in the list is itself a list, its elements are printed using the previous item's row header, with each element's item number for the current list appended. I.e. the header will look like `#.#...#.X` where `#.#...#` represents the previous item's row header constructed by this rule, and `X` is the current element's item number within the current list.
4. If a list appears as the first item in a list, such that there is no "preceding item", a preceding item is assumed for the purpose of generating the "previous item's row header", i.e. the row header will include the index value of `1` even though there was no previous item with that index.

I got it almost working with this code:

```
 var input = new List<object>
        {
             "item 1",
             "item 2",
             "item 3",
             new List<object>{
                 "level 2, item 1",
                 "level 2, item 2",
                 new List<object>{
                     "level 3, item 1",
                      new List<object>{
                         "level 4, item 1",
                         "level 4, item 2"
                      },
                     "level 3, item 2",
                 },
                 "level 2, item 3",
             },
             "last item"
        };


public static string Solve(List<object> list, int level = 0, int subLevel = 0)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    if (level == subLevel)
    {
        level = 0;
    }

    list.ForEach(x =>
    {
        var type = x.GetType();

        if (subLevel != 0)
        {
            result.Append(subLevel.ToString() + ".");
            Console.Write(subLevel.ToString() + ".");
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)))
        {
            var newLevelList = x as List<object>;
            result.Append(Solve(newLevelList, level, level));
        }
        else
        {
            level = level + 1;
            result.AppendLine(level.ToString() + " " + x.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(level.ToString() + " " + x.ToString());
        }
    });

    return result.ToString();
}
```

But it's not working with a 4th level of subItems, like for this example:

I'm getting this output:

```
1 item 1
2 item 2
3 item 3
3.1 level 2, item 1
3.2 level 2, item 2
3.2.1 level 3, item 1
2.1.1 level 4, item 1
1.2 level 4, item 2
2.2 level 3, item 2
3.3 level 2, item 3
4 last item
```

What am I missing? I'm open to a new solution as well.

Comment: Instead of working with `List<T>` and using `List<T>.ForEach` use `IEnumerable` and normal `foreach` (I doubt it will fix your problem though)

Comment: look like you are not incrementing  , the subLevel param but using the level param instead . in line :  result.Append(Solve(newLevelList, level, level));

Comment: Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Please also provide a clear, accurate description of the _exact_ output you want to get given the _exact_ input you've described. I don't see how you get output like `"item 1"` based on the input you claim to be using and the code you've shown. I can certainly imagine a much simpler implementation that would accomplish what you _seem_ to want, but without a more precisely-stated question, it's not clear what answer you're looking for.

Comment: You can't check against `typeof(List<>)` and then cast to `List<object>` because the list contain anything, not just `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail, it's difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. But, based on the examples you've given it appears to me that when the algorithm finds a sub-list, you want to keep the current item index in the row header, and append a new level of indexes starting at `1` to that header. I.e. if you've just shown item `"2 item 2"`, and a list follows that, the first item in the list should be displayed as `"2.1 Item 2 sub 1"` and not, for example, as `"3.1 Item 2 sub 1"` (i.e. the list itself does not count as a new index for that level).

If I've understood correctly, then something like this should do what you want:

```
static string Solve(List<object> source, string prefix = "")
{
    int itemIndex = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (object item in source)
    {
        List<object> listItem = item as List<object>;

        if (listItem != null)
        {
            result.Append(Solve(listItem, prefix + itemIndex + "."));
        }
        else
        {
            itemIndex++;
            result.AppendLine(prefix + itemIndex + " " + item);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Note that rather than passing indexes to the method, I simply pass the header prefix for the row, and rather than using explicit reflection to identify `List<object>` elements in the list, I just use the C# `as` operator to make a conditional cast to the type.

**<edit>**

According to your comment, while you want list items to take on the index of the preceding item, you still want to accommodate list items that have no preceding item. IMHO that's a little weird, but it's easily solved by addressing the special case, as below:

```
static string Solve(List<object> source, string prefix = "")
{
    int itemIndex = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (object item in source)
    {
        List<object> listItem = item as List<object>;

        if (listItem != null)
        {
            // If there was no preceding item, pretend there was one
            if (itemIndex == 0)
            {
                itemIndex = 1;
            }

            result.Append(Solve(listItem, prefix + itemIndex + "."));
        }
        else
        {
            itemIndex++;
            result.AppendLine(prefix + itemIndex + " " + item);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

**</edit>**

If the above does not address your concern, please improve the question so that it more clearly describes exactly what output you want for some specific input.

Comment: This looks pretty good, but I found an issue with this input:  var list2 = new List<object>
            {
                 "level 1",
                 "level 1",
                 new List<object>{
                     "level 2",
                     "level 2",
                     new List<object>{
                          new List<object>{
                             "level 4",
                          },
                         "level 3, item 2"
                     },
                     "level 2, item 3"
                 },
                 "last item"
            };

Comment: see that one list has directly another list, no items before, so I get the output: 2.2.0.1, I can not have that ZERO there

Comment: Neat application of recursion :)